# What are the privacy implications of using Talk-to-Text?

Tags: privacy, voice-recognition

Given that the Android implementation of Talk-To-Text sends your voice to Google's servers, parses your speech into text, then sends the text string back to the handset, what are the privacy implications of using Talk-to-Text?

Does this mean, for example, that anything that I say to my beloved Nexus One is stored on Google's servers?

Do Google TOS refer specifically to this issue?

Comment: Anything you say, can and will be used against you!

Comment: @Ivo LOL, nice sense of humor! Does that mean that you don't have an answer? ;-)

Comment: Well at least that I didn't bother to go read their ToS. If you're worried about privacy, then you shouldn't use such services for things you want to keep private ;)

Comment: I would say it is as bad as having a website, twitter, facebook, etc. or even searching on google, bing, whatever. as eric schmidt said, if you don't want it known, don't post it on the internet (in this case, through a google service) :)

Comment: @Ryan, is that why eric was fired from his position as ceo? :-D

Comment: he wasn't fired, he was promoted.

Comment: @Ryan, sure... Then again, I wouldn't mind being "promoted" with a $300MM bonus. :-)

Comment: I'd bet they do data mine it and and store the data about what people are talking about and searching but I'd be willing to bet it's not stored in a file with your name or IP on it.  It's far more likely your data would be compromised by you losing the phone or by someone using a wifi sniffer or a data breach at some retail institution like TJX.  If you really want to know what's in the TOS you are going to have to venture to be the first person ever to read the TOS.

Comment: @Matt I like your answer. I think keeping some recording could be a great way to advance speech recognition technology. Also, keeping voice signatures as a future worldwide biometric database is not so far fetched (some governments do that already). I didn't think about the data mining though. This seems very google-like.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From Google's [Mobile Privacy Policy](http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en-GB/mobile/privacy.html):

> For products and services with voice recognition capabilities, we collect and store a copy of the voice input you make to the product or service and corrections you make to the returned recognition result. To improve processing of your voice input, we may also continuously record in temporary memory a few seconds of ambient background noise. This recording stays only temporarily on the device and is not sent to Google. If you choose to personalize voice recognition, we will associate your voice data with your Google Account.

Comment: Good find, @Iain.